# Filter string only from line that matches regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I've got some preceding code that outputs this line. Now I would like to isolate just the information in the 'us-west1-c' part. However, this information can change, albeit in the same format. For example, it would read 'us-east1-b' or 'europe-west2-c'. As a result the regex could be said to be `*-*-*` . However, I can't seem to find a way of filtering only this value from the line using this regex.

```
test-group  us-west1-c  zone   default  Yes      1
```

I've tried:

```
grep -ow '*-*-*'
```

Which produces no output.

I've also tried:

```
sed 's/.*\(*-*-*\).*/\1/'
```

Which again fails.

How, can I output only the string that matches my requirements?

Comment: If it is the second non-whitespace substring, use [`awk '{print $2;}'`](https://ideone.com/at3UVM)

Comment: Thanks for showing what you have tried, also please post expected results in post too in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I would like to isolate just the information in the 'us-west1-c' part. However, this information can change, albeit in the same format. For example, it would read 'us-east1-b' or 'europe-west2-c'.

Your string has 6 "columns" and you want to get the value in Column 2. Use `awk`:

```
... | awk '{print $2;}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/at3UVM).

If there is just one value following `*-*-*` format, use

```
grep -o '[^ -]*-[^ -]*-[^ -]*'
# or
grep -o '[^[:blank:]-]*-[^[:blank:]-]*-[^[:blank:]-]*'
```

where `[^[:blank:]-]*` matches 0 or more chars other than whitespace and `-`. See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/fTgQOH).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
 \w+-\w+-\w
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, i tested it.

```
grep "[^ ]*-[^ ]*-[^ ]*"
```

Comment: If you aren't sure of the answer, may be post it as a comment first?